# "Don't look a gift horse in the mouth" synonyms

Tags: synonyms

I always wondered the meaning of this phrase, until I stumbled across [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24539/dont-look-a-gift-horse-in-the-mouth) thread. That knowledge is nice, but the saying itself is now pretty antiquated.

Responses for modern equivalents?

Comment: Ways to express the same idea range from rather severe ("beggars can't be choosers") to almost jocular ("you can't beat the price").

Comment: "Don't be such a bloody ingrate!" ?

Comment: If the idiom is widely understood, why does it matter if it's "antiquated"? Most of the words you used to write this question are several hundred years old; is that a problem for you?

Comment: I agree @phenry. And part of the reason we use proverbs is to lend history's (or the collective wisdom of previous generation's) weight to an idea...

Comment: @phenry - who says the idiom is widely understood? I only know it from my mothers generation, i've never heard it used by anyone in mine, hence the question

Comment: I had a look at the thread you linked to, and no equivalent modern expressions were suggested there. So while I think a couple of the other commenters make a fair point about the usefulness of some proverbial expressions, I also think it's not unreasonable to ask if there's a more contemporary equivalent.

Comment: Perhaps the modern version would be "If you're given a car don't check the milage." I've never heard anyone say that, but I suppose we could try to start a meme;-)

Comment: @myol I’ve heard plenty of people younger than my mother’s generation use it. I’ve used it myself. I’ve never known the expression to not be understood by anyone but small children.

Comment: @RustyTuba I've only ever heard the expression used in relation to something that has come your way accidentally rather than something which has been given to you deliberately by someone else. The matter of ingratitude (except to chance or divine powers) does not really apply in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

> “Don't look a gift horse in the mouth” synonyms?

**ingratitude** or to be *ungrateful*  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/95842?redirectedFrom=ingratitude#eid)

> 1. Want or absence of gratitude; indisposition to acknowledge or reciprocate benefits received; unthankfulness; ungratefulness.

As in:

> Defeating **ingratitude** in our kids is largely dependent on them seeing
>   gratitude in us. Fox News Nov 18, 2018

Comment: The question asked for a modern equivalent to the phrase, not a single word defining the thing the phrase warns against.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the more modern:

> ***Don't look at gift's price tag*** ([PowerThesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/don%27t_look_at_gift%27s_price_tag/synonyms))

In the description of the expression you are giving, [Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Look%20a%20gift%20horse%20in%20the%20mouth) says:

> You look in a horse's mouth to determine its age and/or health. So if someone gives you a horse, and you look in it's mouth, it's *like looking for a price tag*. It's rude!

Answer (score -1):

Related, but also antiquated:
"Don't bite the hand that feeds you!"

Comment: "Don't bite the hand that feeds you" is only very tangentially related (if at all) to the OP's idiom; **and** it's antiquated and not a "modern equivalent".

Comment: is it really antiquated, is my speech that out of date, and this was 4 years ago

Comment: I don't think this one is antiquated - old, sure, but still relevant in that we all still need to eat, and still need to feed our children, guests, pets, etc. But I agree that it's not a good synonym.